# I would like to restore the Unity Launcher on desktop Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: unity, launcher

Seems there may be other issues going on.

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/0292700a-f5b5-4d71-a8f3-5a4fed614821 on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

This is where it stopped.Now what? Sorry, nooby to learn.

I have read many of the posts on restoring the Unity launcher, but none the solutions tried have worked. One day it was working, the next day - gone. The compiz manager will not open also. When trying to reset Unity the following appeared:

```
trpbuktoreed@trpbuktoreed-Dimension-3000:~$ sudo ccsm
[sudo] password for trpbuktoreed: 
sudo: ccsm: command not found
trpbuktoreed@trpbuktoreed-Dimension-3000:~$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
trpbuktoreed@trpbuktoreed-Dimension-3000:~$ sudo apt-get compizconfig-settings manager
E: Invalid operation compizconfig-settings
trpbuktoreed@trpbuktoreed-Dimension-3000:~$ sudo ccsm
sudo: ccsm: command not found
trpbuktoreed@trpbuktoreed-Dimension-3000:~$ apt-get ccsm
E: Invalid operation ccsm
trpbuktoreed@trpbuktoreed-Dimension-3000:~$ unity -reset
Usage: unity [options]

unity: error: no such option: -r
trpbuktoreed@trpbuktoreed-Dimension-3000:~$ unity --reset
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...yes
[LOG]: Moving Internal Files
[LOG]: Copying subdirectory from /home/trpbuktoreed/.compiz/session to /home/trpbuktoreed/.compiz-1/session
[LOG]: Copied file /home/trpbuktoreed/.compiz/session/10671d1d69a6d3cf63148127240250095000000016510054 to /home/trpbuktoreed/.compiz-1/session/10671d1d69a6d3cf63148127240250095000000016510054
[LOG]: Successfully moved internal files
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1800004

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1e00003

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x180028a

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x26000b6

Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't load plugin '/usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so' : libunity-core-5.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't load plugin 'unityshell'
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00090!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00093!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00096!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00099!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0xc00099!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing unityshell options...done
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
Starting gtk-window-decorator
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
```

I hope solution can be found to work and solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem lies in the compiz configuration.

Try reinstalling compiz:

```
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

If it still does not display the dock or dash it could be a driver/opengl issue. Try reinstalling your AMD / Nvidia drivers.